# pubsub alternative in golang

Tags: javascript, go, publish-subscribe, channel

I have simple task that already done in javascript using pubsub, here is the task:

I have object let say `A` and another 2 object that have interest in some element(string in this case), let say `Foo` interest in element `m, n` and `Bar` interest in element `n, o, p`. The interest can intersect.

The A object have method adding/remove element and when that object contain `m, n` element which `Foo` interest in, then that object stored in `Foo` here's the pseudo code in javascript using pubsub

```
var A = {};

var Foo = {
    interests: ['m', 'n'],
    storedObj: {},
    tempObj: {}
};

// Bar same as Foo with different interest ['n', 'o', 'p']

// somewhere in Foo and Bar constructor
// Foo and Bar subscribe too each interests element
// for each interests when add
subscribe('add'+interest, function(obj) {
    // store this obj in tempObj and increment until satisfy all 
    // interest
    tempObj[obj]++;

    // if this obj satisfy all interest then store it in array of obj
    if(tempObj[obj] === len(interests)) {
        storedObj[obj] = true;
    }
});

// for each interests when remove
subscribe('remove'+interest, function(obj) {
    // remove from storedObj
    delete storedObj[obj];

    // decrement tempObj so it can be used for later if the interest 
    // is adding again
    tempObj[obj]--;
});

// inside A prototype
prototype.add = function(interest) {
    publish('add'+interest, this);
    return this;
}
prototype.remove = function(interest) {
    publish('remove'+interest, this);
    return this;
}

// implementation
A.add('m')
 .add('n')
 .add('o')

// then A is stored inside Foo but not in Bar because A doesn't have 
// `p`, but it still stored Bar.tempObj and have value 2 and waiting 
// for `p` to be add

A.remove('m')
 .add('p')

// then A is removed from Foo and stored in Bar
```

I want to porting this task into golang but i don't want using pubsub, i want more idiomatic to golang way. NOTE: i already done using pubsub in golang as well.

Can you show me how to do it in golang? i'm thingking using channel, but and can't find the solution.

Comment: You could use a worker queue. http://nesv.github.io/golang/2014/02/25/worker-queues-in-go.html

Answer (score 2):

Just to give you an idea, not necessarily your real use case.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Publisher struct {
    subscription map[string]chan string
}

func (p *Publisher)Subscribe(interest string) chan string{
    if p.subscription == nil {
        p.subscription = make(map[string]chan string)
    }
    p.subscription[interest] = make(chan string)
    return p.subscription[interest]
}

func (p *Publisher) Add(val string) {
    if p.subscription[val] != nil {
        fmt.Println("Adding " + val)
        p.subscription[val] <- "added " + val
    }
}
func (p *Publisher) Remove(val string) {
    if p.subscription[val] != nil {
        p.subscription[val] <- "removed " + val
    }
}

type Subscriber struct {
    subscriptions [] chan string
    publisher *Publisher
}

func (s *Subscriber) RegisterInterest(interest string){
    s.subscriptions = append(s.subscriptions, s.publisher.Subscribe(interest))
}
func (s *Subscriber) run(channel chan string) {
    for  {
        fmt.Println("Waiting for message")
        m := <- channel
        fmt.Println("Got message : " + m)
    }
}
func (s *Subscriber) Listen()  {
    for _, elem := range s.subscriptions {
        go s.run(elem)
    }

}
func main() {
    pub := Publisher{}
    sub := &Subscriber{publisher: &pub}
    sub.RegisterInterest("m")
    sub.RegisterInterest("n")
    sub.Listen()
    pub.Add("m")
    pub.Add("n")
    pub.Remove("m")
    pub.Remove("n")
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
}
```